# Moving a carousel using setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, carousel

I am trying to use the following code to move carousel elements through every second:

```
function moveCarousel(){
        var x = $('.carousel_title.active');
        var next = x.next();
        x.removeClass('active');
        next.addClass('active');

    }

    setInterval(moveCarousel(),1000);
```

but two things seem to go wrong:

1. The first cycle happens instantly
2. No further cycles occur

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Need more code to go on but you are not resetting your "loop" so there will be no more cycles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should remove the braces on your last line

```
function moveCarousel()
{
        var x = $('.carousel_title.active');
        var next = x.next();
        x.removeClass('active');
        next.addClass('active');

    }

    setInterval(moveCarousel,1000);
```

In this case you are passing a function (`moveCarousel`) to a nother function (`setInterval`) and thus the function is not to be executed (that's what the braces are for) but to be passed like an object.

Your original code was passing `undefined` (because `moveCarousel` does not return anything) to the setInterval function - and setInterval takes a function as it's first parameter - not `undefined`

You could also do this:

```
setInterval(function () { moveCarousel(); }, 1000);
```

where you construct an anonymous function to call moveCarousel.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the function where you should pass the function itself:

```
function moveCarousel(){
    var x = $('.carousel_title.active');
    var next = x.next();
    x.removeClass('active');
    next.addClass('active');

}

setInterval(moveCarousel, 1000); // no () here
```

Currently, you call the function immediately and it evaluates to:

```
setInterval(undefined, 1000);
```

(the function returns nothing so it returns `undefined`), which is not what you want.